# alert in SSJS Library

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have a function in SSJS Library. I would like get Client Side alert in Library. What i tried was not worked. I think I miss something. :(

```
function docAlive()
{
    try 
    {
        var otherDoc:NotesDocument= null;
        if (funcDoc.getItemValueString("DocUNID")!="")
        {
            var otherDoc:NotesDocument = dbKontak.getDocumentByUNID(funcDoc.getItemValueString("DocUNID"))
            if (otherDoc==null)
            {
              hataKod = "10001";
              hataMsg = "There is no document :( Created One";
              print (hataKod +": "+hataMsg);
              view.postScript("alert('"+hataKod + " - " +hataMsg+"');");
            }
        }
        return otherDoc;
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        e.toString();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where resides your code (event, value, ...)?

Comment: Have a look here http://notesspeak.blogspot.de/2013/08/viewpostscript-only-works-for-certain.html and here http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-calling-client-side-javascript-from-server-side-javascript/

Comment: behind a button while submiting..

Comment: this page you mentioned tells me that I cannot do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view.postScript()` will trigger a client-side alert, but as Tim Tripcony mentions, not in all events. And the alert will only be triggered **after** the function and any other code for the partial refresh has completed. At that point the HTML to trigger the (Client-Side) JavaScript alert will be posted back to the browser and the browser will action it.

If you want to throw an error back to the browser, I would strongly recommend XPages OpenLog Logger (and not just because I contribute and support it on OpenNTF). `openLogBean.addError(e)` will log the error to OpenLog and post an error message back to the browser.

The message is passed to the server using `facesMessage.addMessage()`, as documented here http://www.intec.co.uk/returning-error-messages-from-ssjs-through-the-facescontext/. I believe there are additional options for managing different message levels (e.g. WARNING, CONFIRMATION). `FacesMessage` is a standard Java (in this case, JSF) construct, so the documentation for it on the web is valid for XPages as well.